# How do I pivot dynamically sqlite android

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, pivot

I'm using the select below, but I would like the "TURNOS" to become columns. As sqlite / room does not have a pivot option, how can I do this?

```
select tma.turma as TURMAS, tno.turno as TURNOS, count (tno.turno) as QTDE
from (select * from Visita v 
where 
(v.dataCadastro BETWEEN (strftime(v.dataCadastro, '2021-04-01')) AND 
(strftime(v.dataCadastro, '2021-05-31')))) resultado
INNER JOIN Turma tma ON (resultado.turma_id = tma.id) 
INNER JOIN Turno tno ON (resultado.turno_id = tno.id) 
group by TURMAS, TURNOS
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUpEk.png

For example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP3WX.png

I saw some solutions with CASE, but there may be other registrations of "TURMAS" and "TURNOS" later, so it would not help me.

Comment: SQLite does not support pivot, so you will have to do it with a programming language like java.

Comment: Yes, I know (rsrs), I just don't know how to change my code to do it

Comment: You did not post any java code.

Comment: Sorry. Now I understood what you're saying. I don't know how to do it in java O.O